# JSON To HTML Table Compare and Alert

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax

I currently have an AJAX request to update an HTML Table from a JSON file.
I now want a way to alert the changes, alerting with new table items that have been added.

Below is an example of how the HTML table is being populated.
I've tried storing the JSON request into JSON.stringify, storing that into a variable and then comparing that to the last time it ran.. no luck, I only return a true/false, I'd like the compare to return the difference between old and new data.

```
            function populate_table(){
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $.getJSON("data.json", function(data){
                        var update_table = '';
                        $.each(data, function(key, value){
                            update_table += '<tr>';
                            update_table += '<td>'+value.name+'</td>';
                            update_table += '<td>'+value.date+'</td>';
                            update_table += '<td>'+value.address+'</td>';
                            update_table += '<td>'+value.phone+'</td>';
                            update_table += '</tr>';
                        });
                        $('#my_table tbody').html(update_table);
                    });
                });
            };
            populate_table(); 
            setInterval(function(){
                populate_table() 
            }, 5000);
```

Without changing the back end JSON population, is there a way to compare the new AJAX data coming in with the data that came last time, find the differences, and alert? 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you say, "no luck" what exactly do you mean?  If the JSON data is the same, then it should be able to be compared.  Is there some element in the JSON that changes which each AJAX call?  Perhaps a timestamp?  If so, you could exclude that from your comparison.

Comment: Note that every time `populate_table` runs, you're adding another event handler to the document ready event... You probably want to remove that bit and instead wrap your initial call to `populate_table` and `setInterval` in the document ready handler.

Comment: @jwh20 , Editing my post for more context. I am wanting to compare AND find the what was different. When I say "no luck" I mean to say that I'm only able to return a true/false, not the actual difference. I'm not sure how to do the equivalent of Powershell cmdlet Compare-Object as an example.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try store the data in localStorage. And next time when you fetch the data in, you can pull the data from last Ajax call and compare them using loop

Answer (score 0):

Define an arry and push elements in to the array, then you can compare the array with the new data

```
var old_data = new Array;
function populate_table(){
...
old_data .push(name:value.name,
dtae:value.date,
addres: value.address,
phone:value.phone);
$('#my_table tbody').html(update_table);
```

Comment: Is there a way to find the difference in the two arrays with javascript, rather than identifying if there is a difference? For exmaple. return "2" when comparing ["1", "2", "3"] and ["1", "3"]. 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: you can copy the compare function here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-arrays-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Hi this program provides a way to compare two objects and present the differences in a user-friendly HTML table format for easy visualization.

Code

```js
function getObjectDifferences(obj1: any, obj2: any): any {
  if (typeof obj1 !== 'object' || typeof obj2 !== 'object') {
    return obj1 !== obj2 ? [obj1, obj2] : undefined;
  }

  const keys1 = Object.keys(obj1);
  const keys2 = Object.keys(obj2);
  const uniqueKeys = new Set([...keys1, ...keys2]);

  const differences: any = {};

  for (const key of uniqueKeys) {
    const value1 = obj1[key];
    const value2 = obj2[key];

    if (typeof value1 === 'object' && typeof value2 === 'object') {
      const nestedDifferences = getObjectDifferences(value1, value2);
      if (nestedDifferences) {
        differences[key] = nestedDifferences;
      }
    } else if (value1 !== value2) {
      differences[key] = [value1, value2];
    }
  }

  return Object.keys(differences).length === 0 ? undefined : differences;
}

function flattenObjectToCSV(obj: any, parentKey = ''): string {
  const csvRows: string[] = [];

  for (const key in obj) {
    const value = obj[key];

    if (typeof value === 'object' && !Array.isArray(value)) {
      const nestedKey = parentKey ? `${parentKey}.${key}` : key;
      csvRows.push(flattenObjectToCSV(value, nestedKey));
    } else {
      const row = `${parentKey ? `${parentKey}.${key}` : key}, ${value[0]}, ${value[1]}`;
      csvRows.push(row);
    }
  }

  return csvRows.join('\n');
}

function parseCSVToTable(csv: string | undefined): string {
  if (!csv) {
    return '<p>No changes.</p>';
  }
  const lines = csv.trim().split('\n');
  if (lines.length < 1) {
    return '<p>No changes.</p>';
  }

  const headers = ['Attribute', 'Current Value', 'New Value']//lines[0].split(',').map((header) => header.trim());
  const data = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    const values = lines[i].split(',').map((value) => value.trim());
    const row: any = {};
    for (let j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
      row[headers[j]] = values[j];
    }
    data.push(row);
  }

  const tableRows = data.map((row) => {
    return `<tr>
      <td>${row[headers[0]]}</td>
      <td>${row[headers[1]]}</td>
      <td>${row[headers[2]]}</td>
    </tr>`;
  });

  const tableHTML = `
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>${headers[0]}</th>
          <th>${headers[1]}</th>
          <th>${headers[1]}</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        ${tableRows.join('')}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  `;

  return tableHTML;
}

const obj1 = {
  name: 'John',
  age: 30,
  address: {
    city: 'New York',
    zip: '10001',
  },
};

const obj2 = {
  name: 'Jane',
  age: 28,
  address: {
    city: 'San Francisco',
    zip: '94101',
  },
};

const tableHTML = parseCSVToTable(
  flattenObjectToCSV(
    getObjectDifferences(obj1, obj2)
  )
);

console.log(tableHTML);
```

explanation

This program is designed to compare two objects, `obj1` and `obj2`, and generate an HTML table that displays the differences between them. It consists of several functions to perform these tasks. Let's break down the program step by step:

1. **`getObjectDifferences(obj1: any, obj2: any): any`**: This function takes two objects, `obj1` and `obj2`, and recursively compares them to find differences. Here's how it works:

   - If either `obj1` or `obj2` is not an object, it checks if they are different values. If they are different, it returns an array with the values `[obj1, obj2]`, indicating the difference. If they are the same, it returns `undefined`, indicating no difference.
   - If both `obj1` and `obj2` are objects, it proceeds to compare their keys and values.
   - It collects all unique keys from both `obj1` and `obj2`.
   - It initializes an empty `differences` object to store the differences found.
   - It iterates through the unique keys and, for each key:

     - If the values in `obj1` and `obj2` at the current key are both objects, it recursively calls `getObjectDifferences` to compare them. If there are nested differences, it adds them to the `differences` object.
     - If the values are not objects and they are different, it records the difference in the `differences` object.
   - Finally, it checks if there are any differences in the `differences` object. If there are differences, it returns the `differences` object; otherwise, it returns `undefined`.
2. **`flattenObjectToCSV(obj: any, parentKey = ''): string`**: This function takes an object (`obj`) and recursively flattens it into a CSV format. It also appends a parent key for nested objects. Here's how it works:

   - It initializes an array, `csvRows`, to store the CSV rows.
   - It iterates through the keys of the input object.

     - If the value at a key is an object (and not an array), it recursively calls `flattenObjectToCSV` with the nested object and appends the parent key (if any).
     - If the value is not an object, it constructs a CSV row containing the key, the first value, and the second value from the object.
   - It joins all the CSV rows with newline characters to create a CSV string.
3. **`parseCSVToTable(csv: string | undefined): string`**: This function takes a CSV string (`csv`) and generates an HTML table that displays the CSV data. Here's how it works:

   - It first checks if the CSV is `undefined` or empty. If so, it returns a message indicating "No changes."
   - It splits the CSV string into an array of lines and trims any leading or trailing whitespace.
   - It extracts the headers (column names) from the first line, or you can specify them directly as `['Attribute', 'Current Value', 'New Value']`.
   - It processes the remaining lines to create an array of data rows, splitting and trimming values as necessary.
   - It constructs HTML table rows from the data.
   - It creates an HTML table by wrapping the rows in a table structure with headers.
   - Finally, it returns the HTML table as a string.
4. The program then defines two example objects, `obj1` and `obj2`, representing two sets of data. It calculates the differences between these objects using `getObjectDifferences`, flattens the differences into CSV format using `flattenObjectToCSV`, and generates an HTML table using `parseCSVToTable`.
5. The HTML table is logged to the console.

In summary, this program provides a way to compare two objects and present the differences in a user-friendly HTML table format for easy visualization.